# Why tilde and slash doesnt work in Asp.net MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I write this code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"~/Content/Images/");
```

I get `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Content\Images'`.
How should I write correctly? I have the folder "Images" and "Content", and I dont want to hardcode a path. Also, it works when I write in html code like `<img src="~/Content/Images/Img.jpg" for example`

Comment: It doesn't work because `Directory` class has no concept of application roots in ASP.NET, which is why you need to use the technique Habib described to convert it to a path that `Directory` can undertand.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` with `Path.Combine`, like:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine
                             (HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, 
                              "Content/Images"));
```

Or

Use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`, like:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
                                        (@"~/Content/Images/"));
```

Comment: It is strange, but I dont have the property "Current" in "HttpContext" and it doesnt work. Also, the error is absolutely equal to previous (path)

Comment: @bright_light, try `Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "Content/Images"))`

Answer (score 0):

MVC has its own HttpContext (HttpContextBase) which it gets from Controller. If you want to use the general context you just need to use the fully qualified name

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
                                    (@"~/Content/Images/"));
```