# ReadAllLines not finding my text files path? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Whenever executing code that makes use of the respective ActionResult, my program throws the following exception error as shown below:

" System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path ' ... ' "

[image]

I am very confident that i am using the correct path as i have copied it directly from another controller using the exact same path.

Below is the action result used that calls this specific path during its execution:

```
public ActionResult DeleteItemLine(string ReferenceDelete)
        {
            // 1. Read the content of the file
            string[] readLineItems = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("~/App_Data/Item.txt");

            // 2. Empty the file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("~/App_Data/Item.txt", string.Empty);

            // 3. Fill up again, but without the deleted line
            using (StreamWriter writeItems = new StreamWriter("~/App_Data/Item.txt"))
            {
                foreach (string line in readLineItems)
                {
                    if(!line.Equals(ReferenceDelete))
                    {
                        writeItems.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Is there anything blatantly obvious that i am missing here? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Look at the path in your error message. Is that the path you expect? The ~ seems to be taken as a literal part of the path there. You need to figure out how to access the actual project path, rather than the working directory.

Comment: May be a duplicate question.  Take a look a this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590627/why-tilde-and-slash-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why tilde and slash doesnt work in Asp.net MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590627/why-tilde-and-slash-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: This question is very similar to what Jerdine Sabio suggests, however i find his method to be easier to use. Both ways seem to work fine within my program, although i personally would recommend using ' Server.MapPath() ' it appears to be more efficient. Although either way, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Nyerguds Thank you, this is in fact the problem. Refer to the answer by Jerdine. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("~/App_Data/Item.txt")` doesn't understand what `~` means and is based on the root of the server, not the project.

You need to use `Server.MapPath()`, this will accept paths relative to the project.

Use this;

```
string[] readLineItems = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Item.txt"));
```

Comment: Once again, thank you Jerdine, this works perfectly. Really appreciate it man.